# brownian motion and process C1 (order 1 of continuity)

Tags: real-analysis, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

Here is my problem,

With probability 1 (ie: a.s) the brownian motion $(B_t)_{t\in[0,T]}$ is continuous (which is define on a classic probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, (\mathcal{F}_{t})_{t>0}, P)$).

Hence could we write this assertion and why ?

$\forall \epsilon > 0,$ $\exists(B^\epsilon_t)_{t\in[0,T]}\in C^1$ such that $\sup_{t\in[0,T]} |B_t-B^\epsilon_t| < \epsilon$

Comment: For a single trajectory, yes. For all trajectories, no. If you allow $B^\epsilon_t$ to also be random, i.e. to depend on the Brownian motion trajectory, then again the answer is yes. A sledgehammer proof would be to use the Weierstrass approximation theorem.

Comment: Because one trajectory is just some continuous function, and continuous functions may be uniformly approximated by polynomials on bounded intervals. More precisely, it is continuous with probability 1, so your statement should be understood only a.s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assertion is true and we use the **approximation theorem of Weirstrass** for explaining why :

We can approximate uniformly a continuous function defined on a segment by polynomial functions.

Thus, it exists a polynomial function $(B^\epsilon_t)_{t\in[0,T]} \in \mathcal{P}$ (where $\mathcal{P}$ is the set of polynomial function with real coefficient). And obviously $\mathcal{P}\subset {C^\infty}\subset{C^1}$